# How to get the exact number of children with Javascript

Tags: javascript, parent-child

How to get all the children to an object when one of the children contains both properties of child1 and child2.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent1">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1 child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var El = document.getElementById("parent1").children;
console.log(El.length);
```

The console shows the number 5. The number of elements I expected was 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your input returned 4, as expected. I don't know what is different from your text though, but here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rht670/9ayjvs4w/.

```js
var El = document.getElementById("parent1").children;
console.log(El.length);
```

```css
div {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent1">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1 child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```